ASIO 'operation not supported' runtime error on windows when compiled with clang
I am trying to move away from using Visual Studio and use command-line compilation more, however I am having an issue with a project that uses ASIO in its header-only, standalone (non-boost) form compiled using Clang on Windows.
Both Visual Studio and Clang compile without errors, however when running the Clang version, I get a runtime error of thread: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced. when creating a asio::thread
A minimal example;
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#define STANDALONE
#include <asio.hpp>

void foobar()
{
    std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    asio::io_context ctx;
    std::cout << "A ";
    try
    {
        asio::thread thr(std::bind(&foobar));
        thr.join();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

Clang build command
clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp -I"asio-1.30.2/include" -luser32 -lkernel32 -lshell32 -> 0
Visual Studio is configured as 'standard' for a blank C++ application with the exception of asio/include being added to the include path. Visual Studio also builds without issue.
The version built through Visual Studio works as expected outputting A B however the Clang version outputs
A 
thread: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.

I have three possible guesses;

I have not configured ASIO correctly via the #define's
I have not linked the program properly
ASIO does not support building header-only, standalone, on windows using clang


@463035818_is_not_an_ai is this the void _suff() function? I just double-checked and the issue is still present. I will edit the post to remove the ub. Thanks

I would grep the ASIO sources for that string to see what it might be complaining about

@catnip Looked through the source. ASIO was not defining ASIO_HAS_THREADS for some reason, (nor the library using ASIO). Defining it manually seems to fix the issue. Thanks

Figured it out.
As suggested by catnip, I reviewed where the error showed up in ASIO's code and found that it occurs in null_thread.hpp, which asio::thread is typedef'ed to if ASIO_HAS_THREADS is not defined. I thought this would be automatically defined by ASIO or the websocket library that I am using but apparently not.
tl;dr; Add #define ASIO_HAS_THREADS to main.cpp or -DASIO_HAS_THREADS to the build command.

Well done, just adding a note to say that MSBuild is a thing - all the advantages of that magnificent IDE with the ability to build from the command line.  Make it so, number 1.
